# Missing attributes on dynamically loaded class

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, structuremap, filehelpers

I am using Structure Map to load plugins from a child directory.

Both the main app and the plugin reference the FileHelpers dll. FileHelpers has attributes that you put on a class to define what the record is delimited by. These are defined in my plugin. eg.

```
[Delimited('\t')] 
public class Test {
    public string name;
}
```

The FileHelpers utitlity is run from the main app using the class definitions provided by the plugins. If I put the plugin dll in a directory underneath the main application then I get an issue with the FileHelpers library complaining that the attribute cannot be found, however if it is placed next to the main library (same folder), then it works fine.

I have placed some further debug statements into my code and have found that if

```
var type = typeof(Test);
var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

is used and not the specific (the one FileHelpers is using)

```
var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DelimitedAttribute), true);
```

then it finds the custom attributes without any troubles.

I thought this may have been a SM thing but have tried MEF and by doing it using Assembly.Load() and the same thing happens.

Comment: Does `type` represent a `Test` type or a ancestor of `Test`?

Comment: Sorry yes..test represents a Test type

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but `Type.GetCustomAttributes(bool)` doesn't appear to be a valid overload of `GetCustomAttributes` according to [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattributes.aspx). Is this something specific to StructureMap?

Comment: its this one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015452/system-type-getcustomattributes-on-an-assembly-loaded-from-a-network-share-is-no).

According to the blog post [linked in the answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/02/21/536470.aspx), it looks like the plugin dll would need to be strongly named and fully trusted, otherwise `GetCustomAttributes` will filter out the `DelimitedAttribute`.  You could try to add the [`AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx)  to the plugin assembly.